# Copy: How to recover files which have disappeared

Tags: cloud, symbolic-link, copy.com

Some files in Copy have disappeared. How can I recover them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check out the undelete section in the desktop app, which is located under Preferences > Manage My Files. In here, locate the data that you want to recover, select it and click save. The data will then start resyncing to your Copy folder.

[Source](https://copy.zendesk.com/requests/23151)

[Source](https://copy.zendesk.com/entries/33681107-Data-loss)